# Am I at risk of getting banned in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

While I was at lunch today, I was at a restaurant that also happened to be a PokeStop. So naturally while I was there I was playing, collecting the stop and the Pokemon that would come up.

When I got back to work and had some down time I loaded up the game again to see what was around me. For some reason my GPS wasn't updating and it left my avatar at the restaurant which still allowed me to collect the PokeStop. This was about 4 hours ago... my day at work is almost done but I just loaded the game again and my avatar is still in the same place.

Since I'm not technically cheating or GPS Spoofing, could I still get banned for this?

Comment: We can't say for sure if you will be banned or not, we're not Niantic.  However if you don't GPS spoof and the delay is due to a weak GPS signal or other device issue, then you probably won't be banned.

Comment: @JAL I know we aren't Niantic. I guess what I was trying to say was; would this type of situation be considered GPS spoofing?

Comment: I would say no, since you're not faking your location in any way.

Comment: I have often found the GPS to be stuck or just not getting updates. If I restart pokemon go it comes good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am adding this answer based on the voting on my comment.  This answer is only based on personal experience.

We can't say for sure if you will be banned or not, we're not Niantic. However if you don't GPS spoof and the delay is due to a weak GPS signal or other device issue, then you probably won't be banned since you're not faking your location in any way.

Niantic has a section about GPS signal on their [Known Issues](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958208-Known-Issues) page:

> **My location is incorrect, unavailable, or jitters/drifts**
>
> We're constantly working to improve GPS accuracy and stability. In
>   general, GPS accuracy largely depends on the device you're using and
>   your signal/connection strength. To improve your device's location,
>   please review the following settings:
>
> - Pokémon GO has location permissions enabled
> - Internet connectivity is enabled (3G, 4G, Wi-Fi)
> - Device location/GPS is enabled Location/GPS set to high-accuracy mode

Based on this, I believe Niantic acknowledges that GPS is imperfect and and your avatar may jump around based on signal or when you close and open the app.

Answer (score 1):

Most GPS bans from spoofing are caused by the server seeing your location jumping long distances in unreasonable time. Such as is I was sitting on my couch and then next minute miles away with no movement in-between.

So it would be unlikely you will get banned, but it would be a good idea to figure out why your phone's location wasn't changing just to be sure and also so you can return to playing like normal.